# How do you define constants in the MIPS assembly language?

Tags: assembly, mips

I looked online, but the only thing I was able to find was this syntax `PI = 3.1415`, but for some inexplicable reason this does not work in the MIPS simulator program I'm using which is [MARS 4.5](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/papers.htm). I presume it should work if it's part of the MIPS language specification. When trying to assemble a simple hello world program, the compiler says that I've got an invalid language element in my code. Here's the code itself:

```
################################################################################
#                                                                              #
# This is a hello world program in the MIPS assembly language. It prints out   #
# "Hello, World!" on the screen and exits.                                     #
#                                                                              #
################################################################################

# System call code constants
SYS_PRINT_STRING = 4
SYS_EXIT         = 10

.data
    msg: .asciiz "Hello, World!\n"

.text
.globl __start
__start:
    la $a0, msg              # Load the address of the string "msg" into the
                             # $a0 register
    li $v0, SYS_PRINT_STRING # Store the system call for printing a string on
                             # the screen in the $v0 register
    syscall

    li $v0, SYS_EXIT         # Store the system call to exit the program in the
                             # $v0 register
    syscall
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is a substitution macro. MIPS is an instruction set, it doesn't define much beside the instructions themselves. Instructions sets usually don't have a concept of named constants like higher level languages do. Substitution macros are implemented by the assembler, so you need to check your assembler documentation.

For MARS, the directive is `.eqv`. Example :

```
.eqv SYS_PRINT_STRING 4

li $v0, SYS_PRINT_STRING
```